# How to configure plesk to run next js app

Tags: javascript, nginx, next.js, plesk

I have the most basic next app running on a subdomain, consisting of a package.json and a pages/index.js file. I can not get the app to respond properly - if I call the url, I get an 500 internal server error with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nextapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 5004",
    "start": "next start -p 5004",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^10.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
const Index = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Hello Next.js</p>
  </div>
);
export default Index;
```

The app is deployed to a plesk server. When trying to run npm install from the plesk control panel, a whole bunch of cautions/warnings pops up (mostly peer dependencies which I get are not installed by plesk npm install):

```
    npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
    npm WARN @next/react-refresh-utils@10.0.6 requires a peer of webpack@^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN next@10.0.6 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN next@10.0.6 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN next@10.0.6 requires a peer of sass@^1.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN nextapp@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN nextapp@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

npm install from terminal runs smoothly. After that the build command is working both from the plesk panel as well as from the terminal.
Localhost is listening on 5004 after start, as expected (checked with nmap).
The (additional) nginx-directive is:

```
location /  {
    proxy_pass    http://localhost:5004;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

The node setup (in plesk) points to the application and document root, where package.json is located. The application startup file is set to `pages/index.js`.
An equivalent express-server was running without problems.
I am sure there must be a simple solution to get it running, but I can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.